# Can the strict rules of this website be withheld in exceptional circumstances?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Does North Korea accept asylum seekers?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26446/does-north-korea-accept-asylum-seekers)

This question spawned some comments, some of them highly upvoted, mentioning that seeking asylum in NKorea might not necessarily be a good idea. Most of these comments were removed.

Now I understand that in theory, as per the rules of this website, these comments were off-topic, while the question is a good, on-topic question that may (and should) be answered.

The problem is that it is plausible to suspect that behind this question may really be a person who seriously considers avoiding imprisonment in UK by fleeing to NK.

I would say that these are exceptional circumstances that would justify witholding the strict rules of this website. Have mercy upon this man who may soon attempt to make this mistake.

They will, obviously, do as they choose and if they're adamant to flee to NK we cannot stop them; however, the least we can do is to warn them they've chosen one of the worst possible destinations of their defection.

In fact, I would say that this question probably deserves an answer that sums up the resources about the quality of life in NK as well as how people there are likely to be internmented, executed or tortured for extremely slight reasons; since this is probably too much, I at least propose to allow a few off-topic comments.

Comment: In short, no. If someone needs advice about whether or not to go to NK, that's what Expatriates.SE is (assuming the question is even on topic for SE in general).

Answer (score 9):

1. The assumption that the author of that question actually wants to seek asylum in North Korea themselves seems pure speculation to me. Nothing in the question indicates that they seriously plan that.
2. The atrocities committed by North Korea's government are common knowledge.
3. Giving migration advice is not our job. That's what https://expatriates.stackexchange.com is for.

I see no reason why we should have a discussion about whether or not someone *should* seek asylum in North Korea.

Please only post comments below that question which aim to improve the question or fulfill the other purposes explained in the help page for [the commenting privilege](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Regarding 2: Don't you say you've never met people who believe that the atrocities commited by North Korea's government are examples of unsubstantiated Western propaganda.

Comment: @gaazkam I didn't, but when I would meet them I doubt that I as an "obvious victims of western brainwashing" could convince them. So I see no reason to waste my time with trying.

Comment: @Philipp I found [this comment](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26446/does-north-korea-accept-asylum-seekers#comment96922_26446), posted about a month later. Does that change things?